# How does gm get that value in the following question?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, semiconductors

[image]

I'm not sure how gm got its value.

I do know that it gets the value Id/Vgs.

Answer (score 1):

The transconductance \$g_m\$ is given by
$$
g_{m} = \frac{2 I_D}{V_{GS}-V_T}
$$
The drain voltage \$V_D =2V \$ and for DC there is no voltage drop across \$R_G\$. Therefore \$V_{GS} = V_D\$ and
$$
g_{m} = \frac{2 I_D}{V_{GS}-V_T} = \frac{1 mA}{2V - 0.9V}
$$
When the current through the transistor is doubled the gate-source voltage will increase by \$\sqrt2\$. Using this value the resulting \$g_m\$ can be calculated in the same way as before.